# C++ thread get value for each loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I recently start to learn c++, and now I'm playing with multithreading. 
What I am trying to do is to get the current value in a loop.

Like this :

```
std::atomic_int res(0);
void testThread(void){
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    res += i;
}

int main(void){
  std::thread t(testThread);
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    std::cerr << "res : " << res << std::endl;
  }
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

I know this is wrong but I don't know how to fix it... I tried to find how we do it, but I didn't find what I want.

Comment: Print the value of `res` in the loop in `testThread`?

Comment: Join the thread before printing.

Comment: cerr? Maybe std::cout to begin with?

Comment: @NathanOliver If I print the value in the loop I have the correct result but what I want is the result of each loop is print in the current thread not in testThread

Comment: @DimChtz I tried it, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: @SamerTufail There are difference ?

Comment: @tifiou Your not going to be able to do that without a mutex and possible a condition variable.  The while point of a thread is to let it go off and do its work while you get on with what you are doing.  Doing what you want is just an unnecessarily complex way to do a single threaded loop.

Comment: @tifiou yes. Google it. As for the main question, if its just for learning, see an example for a producer/consumer problem in c++

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the information, but it's unnecessarily in the sense of the example I have made or in the general sense ? Because if in the current thread we have loop and in this loop we make complex calculations that require an another loop which make another complex calcultation with the index, it's still unnecessarily to put this loop in another thread and get result each loop ? (I don't know if I'm clear sorry)

Comment: @SamerTufail Oh I didn't know thanks. I'll see an exemple thanks again

Comment: @tifiou: What you really want is a message passing system. The thread can `notify` listeners that there is a new value, and those listeners can print the value.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your code.  Your thread function just finishes too quickly.  Here's an example with *sleep_for()*:

```
atomic_int res = 0;
thread t([&]
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        res += i;
    }
});

for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
    cout << "res : " << res << endl;
}

t.join();
```

By the way, I switched to lambda expression so that no global variable and global function needed.